# Best setup for lightweight cycle touring with Ti road bike

Tags: road-bike, touring, rack, trailer

Should I use rack or trailer? Touring would be B & B normally, but might involve some minimal-gear camping (no cooking) occasionally.

If a rack - what type is best? - there are no braze-ons for a rack, but the Ti frame should carry weight OK and the wheels are strong alloy with steel spokes. Would heel clearance be an issue?

If a trailer - is there a danger of cars pulling across behind and hitting the trailer? I also worry about jack-knifing on steep downhills, and being tempted to take more weight than the (Ultegra) brakes can stop.

Thanks.

PS I'm pretty light myself - about 65kg

Comment: Posting the model of bike and dimensions would help answering this question. In particular the chainstay lengths.

Comment: Also the rough weight of the gear you intend to carry, i.e. 15lbs vs 30lbs.

Comment: 54cm frame - sloping top tube. Max 15kg maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For B&B touring on a road bike, large seat bag works nicely. The weight is higher on the bike than with rear rack and panniers, but it solves clearance issues. Carradice of Nelson makes some nice ones.

Brake power on a road bike is mostly limited by weight distribution. You will lift the rear wheel before locking the front wheel or running out of braking power, so adding weight to the back is no problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid a trailer.

On rear rack you are going to have heel clearance issues.

It may seem extreme but get a front fork with braze-ons.  Braze-on on the inside and outside for really solid rack mounting - check out the Salsa Vaya.  Not going to cost you more than a trailer and ride a lot nicer.

Also consider frame bags. Check out http://www.revelatedesigns.com/. See this set up http://moots.com/our-bike/cross/routt-45/overview/. You can put water bottle cages on the axles.

Comment: The Axiom Streamliner has extensions to give more heel clearance - not sure if that would be enough though? Thanks for the idea but I'd be reluctant to change the forks - too much bother as I normally ride with the road bike club & need lightness etc: the steerer is a very tight fit in the Chris King headset so was a pain to get adjusted right.

Comment: You asked best setup for lightweight cycle touring and that is the question I answered.  You may be better off with a second bike.

Comment: I did say 'with Ti road bike'... why avoid a trailer?

Comment: And that is the question I answered.  I have nothing to add.

Comment: I've used a two-wheel trailer, and they're truly horrible when there's not a lot of room, like on any narrow bridge without footpaths/etc, going through roadworks, or passing bollards.